# memcpy from user space to kernel space

Tags: virtual, memcpy, memory-address

Is it possible to copy data from a user space address to kernel space? If so, who will handle translating VMA so there are no page faults? Would memcpy guarantee this to be safe?

Comment: Well, the kernel is certainly able to do that, isn't it... and module loading, too. If you are a userspace process, though,  I suppose you'll have to get the kernel to map some memory into your address space. Then you can use `memcpy` on the mapped region.

Comment: In order to get any further you need to specify which OS you're talking about.

Comment: I am using Linux 2.6.18.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy_from_user
```

should do what you want